# CGPathAddEllipseInRect always the last color

Tags: ios7, core-graphics

iOS 7. Why both circles are green when CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor values are different. I see that the last color is set to both paths ... Why is this? How to color each path differently?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGMutablePathRef centerCirlce = CGPathCreateMutable();

//circle 1
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1, 0.56f, 0.19f, 1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(centerCirlce, NULL,CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10));
CGContextAddPath(ctx, centerCirlce);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

//circle 1
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.36f, 0.74f, 0.32f, 1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(centerCirlce, NULL,CGRectMake(200, 200, 10, 10));
CGContextAddPath(ctx, centerCirlce);
CGContextClosePath(ctx);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that code is quite hard to read. Can you simplify the code to remove everything that is not relevant to the question about different colors? The only thing I can see is that your colors are hardcoded, are you sure that you are not just drawing one thing on top of the other?

Comment: Simplified, tested. Two green circles. But green is the color of the last circle only. Why both are having the same color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for simplifying your code, now I can see what the problem is.

When you draw the first circle, you create a new path and add the ellipse to that path. Then you configure the context with a color, add the path to the context and add stroke the context's path which consumes it in the  context.

At this point you have drawn one circle and the state of the context has the old color but no path. **However**, the center circle path still has the old ellipse in it.

Then you draw the second circle by adding a new ellipse to the center circle path (which at this point contains both ellipses). Then, just as before, you configure a new color on the context, add the center circle path (which contains both ellipses) and stroke the contexts path (which means that both the old and the new circles will be stroked with the new color, on top of the old color).

Comment: one path = one color. Many paths = many colors! 
I. R. Baboon ... :) Thank's a lot for help, and especially for providing a clue to make me find solution myself!